# ruby how to use #capitalize! and keep string numbers

Tags: ruby

so I'm doing prep work for a ruby dev bootcamp and need to create a program that will capitalize titles. My current code uses `#capitalize!` but when a number is included in the string it is omitted.

```
words = title.split(' ')
words.map! do |word|
  if %w(a aboard about above absent across after against along alongside amid amidst among amongst an and around as aslant astride at
    athwart atop barring before behind below beneath beside besides between beyond but by despite down during except for from in inside 
    into like mid minus near next nor notwithstanding of off on onto opposite or out outside over past per plus regarding round save 
    since so than the through throughout till times to toward towards under underneath unlike until up upon via vs. when with within 
    without worth yet ).include?(word) && word != words[0]
    word
  else
    word.capitalize!
  end
```

so when `what I wish I knew when I was 20` is input I get `What I Wish I Knew When I Was` 
any suggestions?

Comment: Can you give an example? `a = 'hello3'; a.capitalize!` turns `a` into `Hello3`. How is this different for you?

Answer (score 5):

Use `capitalize` instead of `capitalize!`.

By the way, if your intention of `word != words[0]` is to leave any word in the list uncapitalized if it is not the first word, then you are wrong. It does not work like that. The reason is left to you as a homework.

Comment: Because `20.capitalize!` is `nil`. +1

Comment: +1 Sidenote: `nil` would also be returned if `word='A'` for example, since like the numbers, there is no change to the word.

Answer (score 0):

just change `word.capitalize!` to `word.capitalize! || word`

```
"20".capitalize! #=> nil 
"20".capitalize! || "20" #=> 20
```

Comment: why too much work...? non-bang version is enough, as OP is using `#map`.

Comment: point well made +1 @sawa.